# Parameterise SQL Server AS statement?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying parameterise the `SELECT AS` part of this query with the `@ColName` parameter as below. However SQL Server is returning an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@ColName'

Is there some other way this can be achieved or does SQL Server not allow the `SELECT AS` to be parameterised?

```
@UserID varchar(10),
@ColName varchar(10)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
   RETURN 
   (
        (SELECT displayName AS @ColName 
         FROM dbo.AdView  
         WHERE extensionAttribute15 = @UserID)
   )
```

Comment: It does not allow table or column names or similar identifiers to be parameterized. Why do you want to? Why can't this type of substitution happen in the client software instead?

Comment: You "can" do it if you use dynamic SQL, concatenate all the SQL into a string and execute it, but without knowing why I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I have a fairly long SQL query which uses a table valued function. This function returns a column called "displayName". I use it like this:

CROSS apply[dbo].[DisplayNameByUserID](CallDetails.AllocatedToID) AS DisplayNameAllocatedTo

So it takes the value of Details.AllocatedToID and changes it to the value returned from the function.

However, I now want to use this function twice in the same query, for another column. When I use the function a second time I then get the error:

"Ambiguous column name displayName"

Because the column name is returned twice. So I need a way of aliasing it?